# How to automate GNU screen with multiple windows

Tags: python, linux, automation, gnu-screen

I have multiple task to be done on each window of the screen. I need to automate it with some simple script. Any help on this will be appreciated.

```
               Start a Screen named "XYZ" with window "1"
               Start a another window "2"
               Run a particular command on the window "1"
               Run a particular command on the window "2"

         This can continue for multiple windows,
         needed  simple API's to achieve this.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured from the screen man page that , we can send commands to particular screen and window, using the screen with `-X` switch.

```
  '-X' - Send the specified command to a running screen session. 
   You can use the -d or -r option to tell screen to look only for attached or 
   detached screen sessions. Note that this command doesn't work if the session 
   is password protected.'
   Source:  http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html
```

I have just wrapped the screen command in python API's , so just writing a python script suffices my work to automate.

```
       For creating a screen, creating a window and then sending commands.

      `https://github.com/innosam/screenapi`
```

Answer (score 0):

You may look at [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) as an alternative to screen. Among other things it's [control mode](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&sektion=1#CONTROL%20MODE) allows applications to communicate with tmux using a simple text-only protocol.

Comment: will sure give it a try, meanwhile i found that with screen there is a `switch` -X which allows the command to be send to specified running screen.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try as below:

```
# Default screens
screen -t shell1      0
screen -t shell2      1
screen -t server      2       ssh me@myserver
```

Please refer to this [redhat guide for GNU screen](http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/09/27/a-guide-to-gnu-screen/)

Hope this helps.